# Insert records into a table from more than one users at same time

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to insert into same table from more than one users at same time? I have scenario where around 10 users will be inserting to the same table, the number of insertions can be 30/40 per minute from each user.

Will this make a deadlock in the database?

Comment: Yes, it's possible for a database to handle 30-40 commands *per minute*.  That's *really* not a very high volume.  Have you encountered an *actual problem* that needs to be solved?

Comment: Yes, I was using RMS DB, every time two users inserting into the same table at same time it is showing deadlock , seems they have some code, blocking the entire table while on process.

Comment: Then I guess you should correct that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to insert into same table from more than one users at same time?

yes many users can insert at same time,But the insert rate is constrained by so many factors such as indexes,DISK Io..

> Will this make a deadlock in the database?

Inserts alone can never deadlock even if they are conccurent..But other operations occuring at same time like Update,delete..can cause deadlock